# Send Array through url in python django

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, django

I want to sent array through URL in ajax and at back end I want to access that array in python . How can I do that

```
<!--Java script code -->
var arr[] = [1,2,3];
$.ajax(function(){
 url: 'myurl/arr=' + arr,
});
```

How to use that 'arr' in python  for displaying

--edit--

```
def use_arr(request)
  method = request.GET
  list = method.get('arr')
```

The above is python view where I am suppose to use that array but I am not able to access to that array for display purpose.

Comment: You can try use `'myurl/arr=' + JSON.stringify(arr)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Comment: @Alexander But how to access this in django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
$.get('myurl', {arr: JSON.stringify(arr)})
```

Read more about $.get: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

**Python**

```
import json
# ...
list = json.loads(request.GET['arr'])
```